# In-App Currency Offers Callback Testing

Tags: facebook, currency, in-app

Does anyone know how to test the callback for In-App Currency Offers that were just released by facebook other than completing the offers themselves? As I need to see if my modifications are correct before I use them on a live app.

Facebook does not provide a code sample or even a clear explanation on how to test.

Comment: I mean there has to be another way than filling in paid offers. This is ridiculous. They give no code sample how can I assume it will work and modify my code for apps that have real credits purchases. Why is the documentation so bad on Facebook always.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no option for sending a test callback or anything like that - especially maddening because TrialPay *does* (or at least used to) offer this functionality for non-Facebook integrations of their product.

There are free offers & surveys, which are somewhat unreliable in their own right, but may be preferable to actually spending money - kinda depends on how much you value your time. Sure, this is less than ideal, but it's what we've got.